# String replacement not working in script runtime

Tags: powershell

```
$SearchBase = "OU=Users,DC=company,DC=com"
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq "username"} -SearchBase $SearchBase

foreach ($user in $users) {

$NewSurname = $user.Surname -replace "ü","ue" -replace "ä","ae" -replace "ö","oe" -replace "ß","ss"
    
Write-Output $NewSurname

}
```

When I run the commands line per line the replace operator works, if I run the script as a whole it doesn't replace the special characters. Does someone know why?

Comment: Where is the variable `$user` set? Are you missing a foreach loop?

Comment: @ManuelBatsching Yes, I forgot to copy the loop over, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Change `$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq "username"} -SearchBase $SearchBase` into `$user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq 'username'" -SearchBase $SearchBase`. Filter should be a string and since you are testing the SamAccountName there should only be one user returned (or none at all)

Comment: @Theo The filter expression that OP provided is valid according to the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2019-ps

Comment: @ManuelBatsching As you can see there, `-Filter` is of type **string**. It is possible to use a scriptblock notation, but beware: _"if the filter expression is double-quoted, the variable should be enclosed using single quotation marks: `Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$UserName'"`. On the contrary, if **curly braces** are used to enclose the filter, the variable should not be quoted at all: `Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like $UserName}`."_

Comment: With which encoding do you save the script to disk?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I used the UTF-8 encoding, thank you so much for this input, I changed it to UTF-8 with BOM and now it is working. I didn't think about the encoding of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the encoding of the script from UTF-8 to UTF-8 with BOM